# How to solder through-hole components like potentiometers and switches on PCBs quickly and without having to clean flux as a small company?

Tags: cleaning

How to solder through-hole components like potentiometers and switches, 1/4 sockets on PCBs, quickly and without having to clean flux near the joints and little splashes around the PCB as a small electronics company?

I know there is the no-clean flux and I can clean the excess flux that hardens with hot air and IPA but when making multiple units, the cleaning process is starting to be a problem as it is very time consuming.

Is there any way I can solder as usual or with other solder type or with some equipment that doesn't cost too much that would avoid having cleaning it by hand?

I don't mind getting new equipment as long as it is not for mass production really expensive.

I also know there are ultrasonic cleaners but the problem is when I get the PCB, components are already soldered including electrolytic caps. When I solder hardware like potentiometers and switches, etc., it gets messy with the flux around the joints and little dots splashed around the PCB.

Is there a way to solder with very minimal cleaning? They are for sale so I'm interested in matching the clean appearance of bigger company products, if it is possible, or at least close to it. I'm open to all ideas/suggestions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136006/discussion-on-question-by-matrixmodulator-how-to-solder-through-hole-components).

Comment: Why not get one of those dishwashers, but for PCB's. [They are around](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/electronics-assembly/washing). Then you don't have to worry about it anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Consumer products they often just leave the flux on there. If it's rosin or no-clean flux that may be acceptable electronically, so it's just a cosmetic thing. Personally, I've found rosin (such as 'Kester 44') to be less trouble electronically than no-clean in sensitive analog and mixed-signal circuits.

I find a toothbrush and solvent is an acceptable amount of work for small batches (say 20 at a time). If you're into thousands you may want to repurpose a domestic dishwasher. Check local laws about discharge of the waste water into the drain.

Comment: That idea of dishwasher would not work with potentiometers and switches or stuff like that are mechanical right?

Comment: Probably would if they are washable. DIPswitches, for example, are available in sealed or with a cover of polyimide tape that can be removed after cleaning. Similarly, many mechanical relays are designed to be washable but you are supposed to snip a little nubbin off post-cleaning (to vent gaseous stuff that is created during operation).

Comment: Of course the water ideally should be de-ionized (or the boards should be rinsed afterward) and there are vigorous discussions online of what kind of detergent etc. is best.

Comment: Rosin is light acid and will destroy PCB over the time. But it may take years.

Comment: @user263983 we coated boards with rosin flux as standard. It’s pretty stable when not liquid at high temperature (insects entrapped and intact after 100,000,000 years). Also a very good insulator (probably not a coincidence).

Answer (score 2):

Those that use WD-40 for decades , swear by it, those that don't use it, swear at it ;)

If you don't use excessive heat, solder or flux on the solder side, no cleaning is required.  3 seconds max per joint is all you need or  <2 s., if you are good at this.

IF you bake on the resin, it turns to varnish, which means solder time is excessive. Adjust heat source accordingly. It ought to wick in the via but not leak flux out the top side. If you need maximum mechanical strength the solder must wick thru the via.

This commercial solution below by the tank full ought to last a long time.  https://www.techspray.com/pwr-4-flux-remover-8

Put the boards near vertical in a fixture, so it doesn't leak through the top side and allows gravity  to release excess brushed fluid. A compressed air nozzle might remove excess residue in a spray booth if wet with clean air.

Read the MSDS sheets of anything you use.

https://www.techspray.com/Content/Images/uploaded/Documents/Techspray_Industry%20Solvent%20HSE_061716.pdf